# Does QGIS work with Anaconda?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows, anaconda

I am trying to get QGIS to work with the Anaconda distribution of Python but I do not know how to get this to work.

In an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88651/39624) to [Running QGIS through Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/88643/115) it was mentioned that QGIS does not work with Anaconda and I wanted to double check this, just in case there have been any updates in the last few months.

If it is possible to do so, could you direct me a resource that explains how one can go about doing this?

I am using Windows 7 (64 bit) with conda 3.7.1 and python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 13):

I have miniconda 4.8.3 installed on a Linux Mint 19.3 system and, following some instructions reported on [this blog](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/using-qgis-from-conda/) and on the official [conda-forge channel of Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis) I very easily and effectively install QGIS. Hereafter the sequence of the steps I did:

1. Create a new Conda environment: `conda create --name qgis_try_install`
2. Activate the new environment: `conda activate qgis_try_install`
3. Install QGIS: `conda install -c conda-forge qgis`
4. In the above step the necessary packages are downloaded and installed. Then, I can start QGIS GUI by simply typing `qgis` in the Conda environment
   [image: running QGIS from Conda environment]
5. From the Conda environment I am also able to start a python interpreter and import the pyqgis modules
   [image: Using pyqgis functionalities in Conda environment]

I should also mention that the Anaconda installation of QGIS does not interfere with other versions of QGIS previously installed on my system.
[image: QGIS 3.16 installed in Anaconda running together with QGIS 3.10 previously installed on the system]

So, my experience is that Conda supports QGIS installation quite easily and well. Have fun with QGIS!

Comment: The Windows conda install experience is essentially the same as above. There are warnings in the Processing log window that the SAGA and GRASS integration is broken. Presumably this is solvable with extra installation steps (I didn't see any conda packages for them though).

Comment: And you could specify the qgis version you want to install if you are looking for a stable one. If no version is given, the latest one will be installed... `mamba install -c conda-forge qgis=3.28.2` made the job for me.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, QGIS is even available on **Conda Forge**: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis

Comment: Is the graphical interface of qgis also available when I install it via conda ?

Comment: Yes, it has the graphical interface.

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand, QGIS on Windows uses a built-in interpreter, as does the Boundless Geo edition. Unless you can clarify what you're trying to do, then my best guess is no, Anaconda will not work with QGIS.