# Starting QGIS Desktop with Python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I looked at the QGIS official documentation (e.g., [Using PyQGIS in custom applications](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-applications)) and a few questions here (e.g. [Running QGIS through Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88643/running-qgis-through-python)), but I was unable to find an example of a Python script that starts a regular QGIS app.

In other words, I look for the 'official'/recommended way to replicate the same results of running `QGIS.exe` (splash screen, main window visualization, etc.) using a `qgis.py` instead (i.e., without calling a QGIS executable using subprocess):

```py
import logging
from qgis import core

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main():
    qgis_version = core.Qgis.version()
    logger.info('Running QGIS v.%s ...' % qgis_version)

    qg = core.QgsApplication([], True)
    qg.initQgis()

    # some code here that runs the QGIS splashscreen?

    # some code here that shows the QGIS main window?
    
    qg.exec_()
    qg.exitQgis()

    logger.info('Running QGIS v.%s ... DONE' % qgis_version)
```

(I am aware that it is possible to execute a [startup.py](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file), but this question is about writing a Python script that starts QGIS up.)

Comment: For reference, this is how a regular QGIS app is started. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/main.cpp It's not a trivial task to replicate.

Comment: I don't think you can do it indeed, you need to replicate the file indeed main.cpp ...

Comment: I opened a related ticket on QGIS GitHub: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45612

Comment: @gmas80 Out of curiosity, in what situation would it be useful?

Comment: @ComradeChe, for instance, to create a frozen version of a customized QGIS using PyInstaller.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the pattern in the script:

```
from qgis import core
import subprocess

def main():
    qg = core.QgsApplication([], True)
    qg.initQgis()

    print("Starting QGIS")
    
    qgis_exe = r"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-bin.exe"
    process = subprocess.Popen(qgis_exe, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    
    qg.exitQgis()

    print("QGIS is closed now")

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. I am looking for a solution that does not call a .exe, but just replicating the results of calling qgis-bin.exe. I have modified my question. Hope that it is clearer now.